# In a loop, collect tikz nodes in a sequence/list and use it with `fit=` option later

Tags: tikz-pgf

The macro `\CAMKIIRING` draws a hexagon with spheres. Some of them are colored blue and rest red. I collect red nodes in `listA` and pass `listA` to `fit=` parameter. So far, I tried many array related things, none worked. Is there a clean solution to this?

```
\newcommand{\CAMKIIRING}[6]
{
    %% listA = Some list like constainer 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{360/#6};
    \node[] (a) at (10,10) {$\theta$};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#6}
    {
        \IfSubStr {#4} {\i}
        {
            \node[ball color=red,draw,circle,minimum size=#5cm] (r\i) at ($(\i*60:#5)+(#2,#3)$) {};
            %% Only add this node named (r\i) to listA.
        }
        {
            \node[ball color=blue,circle,minimum size=#5cm] (r\i) at ($(\i*60:#5)+(#2,#3)$) {}; 
        }
    };
    %% Often fit is used as following 
    % \node[circle,fit=(r0) (r1) (r4)] (#1) {};
    %% Use listA in fit= .
    %\node[circle,fit=listA ] (#1) {};
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1
    , every node/.style={}
    ]
    \CAMKIIRING{camkii0}{1}{1}{42}{1}{6}; % 42 means 4 and 2 are blue.
\end{tikzpicture}    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a macro to contain the list and use `\xdef` to update it in the loop. Take a look at [this excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26341/89497) from [Andrey Vihrov](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3104/andrey-vihrov). Implemented for your question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\CAMKIIRING}[6]
{
    %% listA = Some list like constainer 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\theta}{360/#6};
    \node[] (a) at (10,10) {$\theta$};
    \def\fitlist{}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#6}
    {
        \IfSubStr {#4} {\i}
        {
            \node[ball color=red,draw,circle,minimum size=#5cm] (r\i) at ($(\i*60:#5)+(#2,#3)$) {};
            \xdef\fitlist{\fitlist(r\i)}
            %% Only add this node named (r\i) to listA.
        }
        {
            \node[ball color=blue,circle,minimum size=#5cm] (r\i) at ($(\i*60:#5)+(#2,#3)$) {}; 
        }
    };

    %% Use listA in fit= .
    \node[draw,circle,fit=\fitlist] (#1) {};
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1
    , every node/.style={}
    ]
    \CAMKIIRING{camkii0}{1}{1}{42}{1}{5};
\end{tikzpicture}    

\end{document}
```

[image: circled circles]